# Validate AWS Cognito JWT Token (Access token)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, jwt

I am using java programming language and using the spring boot framework, I am able to generate JWT token from AWS Cognito using username and password, But now I try to validate the token when I am calling any API and this token is going in the header.
So how can I validate this?

Answer (score 0):

All information on how to verify and validate the JWT can be found here.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html